# Python GCF and Vendored Dependencies

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pip, google-cloud-functions

I'm struggling with deploying a GCF (2nd generation) along with all the required dependencies.

I've got all the dependencies enlisted in the `requirements.txt` file:

```
google-cloud-secret-manager>=2.16.1
google-cloud-resource-manager>=1.10.1
```

As per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#vendored_dependencies), I download them with the following command:

```
pip download
  -d /user/projects/function/deps/ 
  -r /user/projects/function/src/requirements.txt 
  --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 
  --python-version 311 
  --only-binary=":all:" 
  --implementation cp
```

So the file structure looks like this:

```
/user/
└──project/
    ├── function/
       ├── deps/
          └── ... downloaded *.whl dependencies
       ├── src/
          ├── requirements.txt
          └── ... other Python files
       └── main.py
```

Then I deploy with the following command:

```
gcloud functions deploy "my-demo-function" \
    --gen2 \
    --region=region \
    --project=project \
    --runtime=python311 \
    --timeout=540 \
    --trigger-topic=my-demo-topic \
    --entry-point=process_event \
    --set-env-vars=GOOGLE_VENDOR_PIP_DEPENDENCIES=deps \
    --source=/user/projects/function/
```

During the deployment, I got the following error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'resourcemanager_v3' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

I tried setting the `GOOGLE_VENDOR_PIP_DEPENDENCIES` variable to:

1. `deps`
2. `/workspace/deps`

Unfortunately, neither of these options worked. Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Only include the `requirements.txt`. Skip your steps to include `vendored dependencies` as that is not required. In most cases, you do not want to include packages that were built for your computer. Just include the deployment files and your source code. Also, make sure you have a correctly written `.gcloudignore` file. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore

Comment: Note: `vendored dependencies` should only be source code and not Python Wheels, which are compiled for particular architectures. Based on your post you do not have any `vendored dependencies` to include.

Comment: As @JohnHanley said, you have to skip the steps with `vendored dependencies`, you only need to deploy your `Cloud Function` with your `Python` files and the `requirements.txt` file at the root folder of your function.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to download the dependencies from an internal Nexus repository. As there is no way to access the Nexus instance from GCP, I need to deploy dependencies along with the function.

Comment: That detail is not in your post. Include all details when you post a problem. You can download and include source code but not compiled wheels. Please read our comments in detail.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue.

Instead of downloading dependencies:

```
pip download
  -d /user/projects/function/deps/ 
  -r /user/projects/function/src/requirements.txt 
  --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 
  --python-version 311 
  --only-binary=":all:" 
  --implementation cp
```

I install them:

```
pip install
  -t /user/projects/function/deps/ 
  -r /user/projects/function/src/requirements.txt 
  --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 
  --python-version 311 
  --only-binary=":all:" 
  --implementation cp
```

And then deploy the function:

```
gcloud functions deploy "my-demo-function" \
    --gen2 \
    --region=region \
    --project=project \
    --runtime=python311 \
    --timeout=540 \
    --trigger-topic=my-demo-topic \
    --entry-point=process_event \
    --set-env-vars=PYTHONPATH=/workspace/deps \
    --source=/user/projects/function/
```